# Maven test dependency in multi module project

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

I use maven to build a multi module project. My module 2 depends on Module 1 src at compile scope and module 1 tests in test scope.

Module 2 -

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>blah</groupId>
       <artifactId>MODULE1</artifactId>
       <version>blah</version>
       <classifier>tests</classifier>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
```

This works fine. Say my module 3 depends on Module1 src and tests at compile time.

Module 3 -

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>blah</groupId>
       <artifactId>MODULE1</artifactId>
       <version>blah</version>
       <classifier>tests</classifier>
       <scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>
```

When I run `mvn clean install`, my build runs till module 3, fails at module 3 as it couldn't resolve the module 1 test dependency. Then I do a `mvn install` on module 3 alone, go back and run `mvn install` on my parent pom to make it build. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you please share what your parent pom looks like?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

I have a doubt about what you are trying to do but but I'll assume you want to reuse the tests that you have created for a project (module1) in another. As explained in the note at the bottom of the [Guide to using attached tests](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html):

> Note that previous editions of this guide suggested to use `<classifier>tests</classifier>` instead of `<type>test-jar</type>`. While this currently works for some cases, it does not properly work during a reactor build of the test JAR module and any consumer if a lifecycle phase prior to install is invoked. In such a scenario, Maven will not resolve the test JAR from the output of the reactor build but from the local/remote repository. Apparently, the JAR from the repositories could be outdated or completely missing, causing a build failure (cf. [MNG-2045](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2045)).

So, first, to package up compiled tests in a JAR and deploy them for general reuse, configure the `maven-jar-plugin` as follows:

```
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.2</version>
       <executions>
         <execution>
           <goals>
             <goal>test-jar</goal>
           </goals>
         </execution>
       </executions>
     </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Then, install/deploy the test JAR artifact as usual (using `mvn install` or `mvn deploy`).

Finally, to use the test JAR, you should specify a dependency with a specified type of `test-jar`:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.myco.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: Pascal. First of all thanks a lot for answering all the maven questions !!

Regarding this question. I have still a problem. I have some testBase class in one of my core modules that i want to use in all of the child objects.


We have currenly the maven build in our CI. If i dont want to do any install of deploy to the test-jar and just to check out a fresh copy from trunk and run the mvn test.

This fails , since i dont have the test-jar anywhere yet. 

Any idea how to deal with that ?

Comment: @Roman Running install is the "natural" way. But it looks like you found a workaround.

Comment: It seems to be this issue 3559 not 2045 that is the hold up at this point:  http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3559

Comment: Altough this explains what is happening it does not provide workaround. It just suggest to do what OP (and eg I) is already doing.

Comment: Solution still works to this day, even with multi module maven projects

Answer (score 20):

Regarding to my comment to Pascals question i think i have found a stuitable answer :

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
        </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}\target</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

The main difference here as you see here is the `<phase>` tag.

I will create the test-jar and it will be available in the compile phase of the tests and not only after the package phase.

Works for me.

Comment: Yes, very convenient. Thanks for sharing. I guess the deploy approach is better only when you have a corporate directory (yes, I know this is strongly recommended). Thanks @Roman