# Maven can't find Package in Test-Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, testing

I'm trying to use a test-jar dependency in another maven module during testing. So just like in this question ([Maven test dependency in multi module project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725476/maven-test-dependency-in-multi-module-project)) and in the maven guides, I placed a test-jar goal in module A, and put a dependency on it in module B where I want to use some classes from A in my testing. Eclipse recognizes all my classes properly, and when I run a clean install from my project root, then run `mvn dependency:tree` in module B, I see module A.

However, when I run a `mvn clean install`, maven complains that

```
... package 'my.package.in.module.A' does not exist
```

Structure of my project is

```
reactor
--module A
--module B
```

Pom A:

```
  ...
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.2</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <goals>
         <goal>test-jar</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
...
```

Pom B:

```
 ...
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.company.moduleA</groupId>
  <artifactId>module-A</artifactId>
  <version>moduleA-version</version>
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I left out the version/artifact/etc for privacy, but they match up properly.

Am I missing something?

EDIT: This is maybe not the right solution to this question in particular, but I just removed the `<type>test-jar</type>` and got it working without using that.

Comment: In all things Maven ... a POM speaks a thousand words.

Comment: You commented too quickly... the POM was coming :)

Comment: That all seems correct. ... And the reactor's `pom.xml` has a proper `<modules/>` section...? Are you sure there isn't a cyclic dependency between A and B?

Comment: Has modules section and no cyclic dependency.

Comment: @eipark Can you provide more context around the "does not exist" message? What phase / goal does this occur in? Have you tried running with `-X`?

Comment: Is Maven actually installing the artifact locally and then in the remote repository? Can you verify that this exists in your local repo at the time of failure?

Comment: It says `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3:testCompile.......Compilation failure`. I see the test jar in the Module A target.

Comment: As your edited by removing the `<type>test-jar</type>` and it worked. Dose that missing class place at `src/main/java` or `src/test/java` of the Module A?

Answer (score 7):

There is a workaround. Use -DskipTests instead maven.test.skip. The
second one also skips the compilation of the tests so the test-jars
aren't being created.

See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html