# How to script maven commands in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-shade-plugin

I have a maven project in Eclipse with a bunch of local project dependencies.

Building with the Maven assembly plugin or shade plugin is a pain because I first have to build and install all of the local project dependencies before I can build my main project.

Does m2e provide a way to script a sequence of arbitrary maven commands?  I know I can script everything from the command line, I just don't know where m2e's instance of maven is installed, and I'd like to avoid installing a separate instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered creating a [multi-module Maven project](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) that "contains" the dependencies? That would allow you to build just the container and Maven automatically takes care of building the component modules. Eclipse's m2e supports multi-module builds so there wouldn't be anything special to do for Eclipse.

Comment: Ah, that might work for me.  I'll check it out, thanks!

Comment: I tried that, but there were two things I didn't like about it: 1) how would you ever include a module in other multi-module projects? 2) module A had test depdendency on module B, and maven failed to include A's classes when building B's tests in the multi-module project.  Worked fine when I shell scripted the module build order and ran `mvn package` on the main project.

Comment: I remember the first job I had where we used a multi-module maven project, we always got all kinds of weird errors and I ended up hating maven.  Now I started using it in non-multi-module projects and I've been pleasantly surprised how well it works...

Comment: The test dependency thing is tricky; basically you have to configure A to produce a test JAR, then declare the dependency on A as a `test-jar` dependency. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1733745/639520

Comment: I see Maven as a necessary evil; necessary because the Java community has latched on to it, evil because it's, well, evil.

Comment: @ERiz actually it was half my fault about the testDependency, module A needed to have JUnit as a compile dep, rather than a test dep, yet I wasn't seeing errors, I think because it was already built successfully by Eclipse using extra Eclipse classpath stuff.

Comment: @ERiz that is, Module A exports classes in a *non-test jar* that Module B needs to use to compile its tests.

Comment: Yeah it is a necessary evil, but thankfully scripting the module build sequence isn't that hard, so multi-module maven projects aren't a necessary evil for me.

Comment: @ERiz aha, I figured out that if I use "project aggregation" with a multi-module project (i.e. no parent POM inheritance), the module that contains the shade plugin will automatically build the shaded jar after everything else when I run `mvn install` on the "parent" pom.  So it works!