# Why doesn't IntelliJ Idea find Maven dependencies from another Kotlin module?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, kotlin

Imagine I have two Maven-based projects with Kotlin code, [prjA](https://github.com/dpisarenko/2016_06_01_kotlinMavenProblem/tree/master/prjA) and [prjB](https://github.com/dpisarenko/2016_06_01_kotlinMavenProblem/tree/master/prjB).

Test class [SomeTest](https://github.com/dpisarenko/2016_06_01_kotlinMavenProblem/blob/master/prjA/src/test/java/prjA/SomeTest.kt) in `prjA` references a [class](https://github.com/dpisarenko/2016_06_01_kotlinMavenProblem/blob/master/prjB/src/main/java/com/mycompany/ValidationResult.kt) and [function](https://github.com/dpisarenko/2016_06_01_kotlinMavenProblem/blob/master/prjB/src/main/java/com/mycompany/utils/Utils.kt) defined in `prjB`:

```
class SomeTest {
    @Test
    fun prjACanReferencePrjBStuff() {
        val valRes = ValidationResult()
        val correctValRes = createCorrectValidationResult()
    }
}
```

When I

1. run `mvn clean install` in [prjB](https://github.com/dpisarenko/2016_06_01_kotlinMavenProblem/tree/master/prjB),
2. update the dependencies of `prjA` in IntelliJ Idea and
3. run `mvn clean install` in [prjA](https://github.com/dpisarenko/2016_06_01_kotlinMavenProblem/tree/master/prjA),

I get errors - Maven can't find the classes defined in `prjB`:

[image: Error in IntelliJ Idea]

Why? How can I fix it?

**Notes:**

1. Kotlin classes are [publicly visible](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html) by default. I don't get any errors during `mvn install` of `prjB`.
2. The Maven repository contains `prjB` artifacts and IntelliJ Idea references the right Maven repository.
3. When I try to build `prjA` from the command line, the build succeeds.
4. Invalidating IntelliJ Idea cache and rebuilding the project doesn't help.

**Update 1:** I need a solution, which allows me to use `prjB` not only in tests.

**Update 2:** Everything works perfectly fine, if I rewrite Kotlin classes in `prjB` in Java.

Comment: Make a multi module build from it and define the appropriate dependencies between them.

Answer (score 1):

If you need regular classes from prjB, add main dependency to prjA.
If you need test classes from prjB, add test dependency to prjA.

To add main dependency to another module:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.your.group</groupId>
      <artifactId>prjB</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

To add test dependency to another module:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.your.group</groupId>
      <artifactId>prjB</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725476/maven-test-dependency-in-multi-module-project) is an example on test dependency.

Comment: See my update 1. I need to find a way to use `prjB` not only in tests, but in the normal code as well. Will you proposal work in this case?

Comment: See the first code snippet of doge, this will set a 'normal' dependency.

Comment: How is the dependency from your first code snippet different from the dependency on `prjB` in my [example](https://github.com/dpisarenko/2016_06_01_kotlinMavenProblem/blob/master/prjA/pom.xml) ?

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko then it's problem in the IDE. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454822/import-maven-dependencies-in-intellij-idea)